# Google Directions API not giving JSON response data

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-directions-api

The directions api is not working in my Flutter web app. When I request I get no response JSON data and this runtime error:

```
<error: Bad state: Source maps are not done loading.>
    at Object.createErrorWithStack (http://localhost:49650/dart_sdk.js:5093:12)
    at Error._throw (http://localhost:49650/dart_sdk.js:20399:18)
    at Error.throwWithStackTrace (http://localhost:49650/dart_sdk.js:20396:18)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:49650/dart_sdk.js:40921:18)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:49650/dart_sdk.js:40778:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:49650/dart_sdk.js:40784:13)
    at http://localhost:49650/dart_sdk.js:36261:9
```

Here is my http request

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:order_online/constants.dart';
import 'package:order_online/models/coordinates.dart';
import 'package:order_online/models/route_info.dart';

class Directions {

  Future<RouteInfo> getRouteInfo() async {
    final url = Uri.parse(
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Toronto&destination=Montreal&key=$googleAPIKey');

    final response = await http.get(url);
    // Error here ^

    final relevantBody = json.decode(response.body)['routes'][0]['legs'][0];
    return RouteInfo(
        distance: relevantBody['distance']['text'],
        duration: relevantBody['duration']['text']);
  }
}
```

My google account has billing set up. The API key is valid and working with other google apis in the same Flutter project. And when I copy and paste the url from the request into my browser I get the correct result. When I try to get the response status I cannot because the error is thrown before and there is no response.

Comment: You can check your response status

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I know but there is no response status, I get an error with no response.